# Deep nested relationship whereHas and with

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have been stuck on this one for a few days, in part due to the depths of the query. You might as well have the true query in all its current glory too:

```
    $submissions = Submission::with([
        'authGroupPriority',
        'authGroupPriority.groupData',
        'claimData',
        'claimData.claimUser',
        'claimData.claimForm',
        'claimData.claimStatus',
        'authGroupPriority.formData',// => function($query){$query->where('forms.id', 1);},
        'authGroupPriority.users' => function($query){
            $query->where('users.id', Auth::id());
    }])->whereHas('authGroupPriority.users', function($query){
        $query->where('users.id', Auth::id());
    })/*->whereHas('authGroupPriority.formData', function($query){$query->where('forms.id', 1);})*/
        ->get();
```

Right so most of the relationships are one to one or one to many relationships here and this is the desired outcome:

```
Submission
WHERE current user is in list of authGroupPriority.users
WHERE submission.level EQUALS claimData.claimForm.authGroups.level
```

Thats the basics anyway. I am happy with setting up whereHas and with functions to be the same, just can't work out how to pass in submission level in a whereHas (or with) on the deep nested relationship. Any ideas or am I overcomplicating this somehow?

EDIT:

After spending the afternoon on this query I finally got the one that works (in SQL)

```
SELECT * from submissions
  INNER JOIN(SELECT users.uid, forms.id, forms.name, claims.id AS claimsId FROM claims
          INNER JOIN submissions ON submissions.claim = claims.id
          INNER JOIN forms ON forms.forms.id = claims.form
          INNER JOIN users ON claims.user = users.id) F ON F.claimsId = submissions.claim
  INNER JOIN (SELECT auth_group_members.priority FROM auth_group_members
          INNER JOIN groupmembership ON auth_group_members.authGroup = groupmembership.groupID
          WHERE groupmembership.userID = 1) AG ON AG.priority = submissions.chainPosition
GROUP BY submissions.claim;
```

Its not pretty but it works. The question is, is this Laravelifiable (new word I think I'm going to claim)? (withs and wherehas's)

EDIT 2:

The SQL above isn't right but its almost right. Just got one more filter to add and thats the submission level = the auth groups level

EDIT 3:

```
    SELECT * FROM submissions
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT users.uid, forms.id, forms.name, claims.id as claimsId FROM claims
                        INNER JOIN submissions ON submissions.claim = claims.id
                        INNER JOIN forms ON forms.forms.id = claims.form
                        INNER JOIN users ON claims.user = users.id) F ON F.claimsId = submissions.claim
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT auth_group_members.form, auth_group_members.priority FROM auth_group_members
                        INNER JOIN groupmembership ON auth_group_members.authGroup = groupmembership.groupID
                        WHERE groupmembership.userID = 1) AG ON AG.priority = submissions.chainPosition AND AG.form = F.id
                GROUP BY submissions.claim
```

Comment: what you want to achive??

Comment: Its really hard to write in a short statement. I will try to compose it properly.
--
All submissions >
Filtered by user in allowed group >
Filtered by allowed group level to current submission level
--
Say submission level was 2 and the group level was 1, the user would have access to the submission but it would be filtered out as the level was not the same

Comment: have you tried using join?

Comment: I was hoping to do it the "laravel" way first. I'll give it a go during the day tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I managed to get it working in SQL and current using a `DB::select()` statement to output the information. It would be nice to convert this to an eloquent setup but its a little complex.